# how to deploy c# code in 2012 visual studio on azure

Tags: azure

Can we deploy c# code from visual studio(2012) into azure virtual machine?
if we can deploy what are the steps to deploy the code.Please help me out of this thank you..

Comment: It is better if you can clarify which type of application you are trying to deploy?

Comment: i just want to deploy web application into azure Virtual machine.Its is mandatory to install SDK in visual studio to push my code into Virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install WebDeveloper Tools and Azure SDK to get Connected Services and connect to Azure.

[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/) You can found more information.

Check the section: April 2013 (version 2.0) - retired